# array looping (loop counts is greater than array indexes)

Tags: php, for-loop

This is my array and my for loop here is the problem my array indexes is only 6 indexes but my rows is 15 counts that's why the index 7 and about will reduce an error. My question is how to go back into index 0 if the loop reach the index 7. I have a solution below, but I like my solution. Please look my solution below and please suggest another solution or other methods to solve my problem.

```
$row = 15;
     $array = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday");
    for($i = 0; $i <= $row; $i++) { 
        echo $array[$i]."<br />";
     }
```

Here is my solution, and I know this is not a good solution that's why I need your need help:

```
$array[7] = $array[0];
    $array[8] = $array[1];
    $array[9] = $array[2];
    $array[10] = $array[3];
    $array[11] = $array[4];
    $array[12] = $array[5];
    $array[13] = $array[6];
    $array[14] = $array[0];
    $array[15] = $array[1];
    $array[16] = $array[2];
    $array[17] = $array[3];
    $array[18] = $array[4];
    $array[19] = $array[5];
    $array[20] = $array[6];
```

Comment: what exactly is the question now?

Comment: i want to repeat the array if the array index is equal to 7...

Comment: I'm afraid this is too much code. Please reduce your question to a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: only if how to repeat the is the problem

Comment: i put all that codes to make u understand

Comment: but which array (there are about 12 in this code)? What do you mean with _"repeat the array"_?

Comment: the last code is my problem

Comment: how to make that code short?

Comment: ok, after 15 minutes studying your code I think I found out what you wanna do: you have a number of days f.e. 24, and need to reduce by x times 7. basicly. So 24/7=3,4.. => 3 weeks + (24-3*7=) 3 days

Comment: yes sir...because my array index is about 6 indexes...that is why i want to repeat the loop if the $array index is equal to 7... i want to go back into index zero

Comment: so you could just do the simple maths I described: `$days = 24;
$weeks = intval($days/7);
$leftoverdays = $days-$weeks*7;`

Comment: no i dont want to multiply by 7 because every $array index have a different value that's why all i need is to repeat the array using for loop

Comment: Example $array[0] = monday rates value="5,000.00",  $array[1] = tuesday rates value="3,000.00" and so on..

Comment: i want to know if there is a way to repeat an array values using loops?

Comment: ...but you can use these results to 'copy' the matching arrayvalue: `$array[$days] = $array[$leftoverdays];` (though I still doubt you really need to 'copy' them. I try to lead you to a better solution than having an array with multiple times the same content. Because this is most likely a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer of my own question...

```
$row = 15;
 $array = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday");
 for($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) { 
     echo $array[$i % 7]."<br />";
 }
```